# Finder has trouble mounting folders with special characters

Tags: finder, network, smb, nas

I know in general it's bad to name files and folders with special characters.

As an example:

I created a folder on our NAS and named it `test%` so far so good, no error on creating it like "you can't name a folder like this" (I remember this came up on Windows or I believe also on mac with some characters but can't figure out which right now)

Now I copy the `smb://` path of it via <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> and make it a clickable link in an email.

So the path is for example `smb://Server/folder1/test%`

Finder opens and a small windows comes up "Connecting to `smb://Server/folder1/test%`".

When I do this, the loading bar is jumping back and forth forever and nothing happens.

When I do the same thing but with a folder without a special character: `smb://Server/folder1/test` it works and Finder can mount the folder as expected.

Is this a bug? Can I fix it somehow (besides stopping to name folders and files like this)?

My Mac is currently running Big Sur 11.3.1

**Quick edit:** 
I tested some more special characters like `$`, `&`,`.` (they work). `/` didn't and also I got an error that this folder doesn't exist (although it does).

But `%` displays the correct folder name in the loading bar but doesn't do anything.

[image]

Comment: % is a URL encoding method - probably a really bad choice for a URL. %20 is a space etc

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you. I will test this with other characters. And I know probably the most special characters are a bad choice for folder names. But everybody in the office has stick to the rules and not name it like this. I was wondering if I can do anything about it if someone doesn't stick to the rules.

Comment: No. You have to teach people. It's simply best to tell them alphanumeric only, no umlauts, etc, no spaces, use underscores. Don't let them use edge cases & you won't have to fix them ;) This is especially important if you have multi-platform access, as illegal characters on one OS may not be on another. I'd make a rule on replacing umlauts too, decide whether Müller should become Muller or Mueller & stick to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having to learn the entire illegal character list for every OS, it's best to train people to an easy subset of these rules…

Alphanumeric only. No umlauts, etc. No spaces, use underscores.
You could probably make a call on Capitals, most OSes are case insensitive, so it shouldn't matter.

Don't let them use edge cases & you won't have to fix them;) This is especially important if you have multi-platform access, as illegal characters on one OS may not be on another.
I'd make a rule on replacing umlauts too, decide whether Müller should become Muller or Mueller & stick to it - that way people will not need three guesses to find an otherwise known name.
Using underscores with no spaces just makes paths simpler - no-one has to guess whether they need `folder name` `folder\ name` `folder%20name` or `"folder name"` to find something, it's **always** `folder_name`.

% is a URL escape [encoding] method as seen above, %20 means space - best to be avoided for names in URLs.