# MacOS: Specify a folder as Windows Server / System shared

Tags: macos, windows, smb

I'm an irregular Apple user (except for my iPhone) since I only work with Apple PCs & Laptops at work. So here is the issue. When a User with an iMac 2017 running Mac OS Mojave (forgot the exact number) is working on the network share, he/she can use special characters that either don't exist under Windows or that are not allowed under Windows. For example: *, ?, ", <, >, |
When I tried with an old MacBook Air 2010 (late) running High Sierra (10.13.6) the only character it didn't like was the :. Plus the characters that I have never seen or used on a Windows PC are the < & > with an extra line underneath.

So since Mac OS supports such characters in the folder path, it would be good to have an option to define a network shared folder from a Windows device as Windows or Microsoft hosted which would disallow any special characters that are either unknown to Windows or not allowed in Windows. I don't know if an option like this exists in MacOS and I was unable to find something myself except for instructions on how to add a Windows share or network share on the Apple Devices.

To give some more details the share is hosted on a virtual Windows Server 2019 running SMB.

Perhaps there is a way to mark certain special characters as illegal file name characters, too. That would also be an option if it's available.

Maybe someone here know something or got an idea for this. This is also only a preventive question to avoid issues between both systems.

Comment: You really just have to train users to not do this. Alphanumeric, no accents; underscores, no spaces. Keep the rules simple. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421369/finder-has-trouble-mounting-folders-with-special-characters/421379#421379

Comment: @Tetsujin If only it was always that easy. ^^
I mean tell pure Apple user to do this when they are so used to doing so for years. Some manage it and some don't. But to be honest a feature like "This is a windows SMB-share" would be nice.

Comment: It might indeed be nice, but as far as I'm aware one doesn't exist. I can't test anything at the moment as my only Win/smb machine is down for service

Comment: Shame that this is not a thing already. I mean Apple got the AD integration as far as I know. We don't use it here but at a former job I remember that we added the iMacs of a school to their domain and they were all working happily with it. But then again it's easier to educate a teacher than some people that do their work on them. I will not throw it out of the window of course but it will take some time to get them to never ever use those characters for file names. The easiest way to teach this is the programmers way of just denying such entries. Example Online fill-out Forms ;)